# Is there a way to make Anchor to Page the default in Libre Office

Tags: libreoffice-writer

Is there a way to make Anchor to Page the default in Libre Office?

When a picture or frame is inserted in Libre Office writer the default behaviour is to anchor it to paragraph. Is there a way to change this behavoir so that by default it is anchored to the page?

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/questions/550240/make-libreoffice-writer-insert-pictures-as-character-by-default

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround :
You can create a style to apply to your images.
Insert an image, change its settings so it matechers what you wish. Select the image, and in the styles panel, create a new style (in the Frames style list), choosing 'new style from selection' in the drop-down menu from the icon in the top-right corner.

Then, just apply the style to all the newly inserted images.